# Take function from dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to perform calculation based on inputs defined in a dataframe. Refer the dataframe `RefDf` below. It has 3 columns - column name, calculation, New Variable Name. When `Calculation` column contains count, we should use `n_distinct( )` function.

```
RefDf <- read.table(text = "Variables   Calculation NewVariable
Sepal.Length    sum Sepal.Length2
Petal.Length    count   Petal.LengthNew
", header = T)
```

**Manual Approach** - Needs to be automated via inputs in `RefDf`. `Species` remains same for grouping.

```
library(dplyr)
    iris %>% group_by_at("Species") %>% 
      summarise(Sepal.Length2 = sum(Sepal.Length,na.rm = T),
                Petal.LengthNew = n_distinct(Petal.Length, na.rm = T)
                )
```

I am looking for dplyr or base R based solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# using data.table
dt <- as.data.table(RefDf)
dt[Calculation == "count", Calculation := "n_distinct"]
# function for doing grouping calculation
inner.fun <- function(calc, data, column, group="Species"){
  print(column)
  data.dt <- as.data.table(data)
  data.dt[, .(as.numeric(get(calc)(get(column)))), by=group][]
}
out <- dt[, inner.fun(calc=Calculation, data=iris, column=Variables), by=NewVariable]

# reshape from wide to long
out2 <- dcast(data=out, Species ~ NewVariable, value.var="V1")

# convert to data.frame
out_df <- as.data.frame(out2)
out_df
         Species Petal.LengthNew Sepal.Length2
1     setosa               9         250.3
2 versicolor              19         296.8
3  virginica              20         329.4
```

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. I am looking for dplyr or base R based solution.